# ASICs not receiving all nonces

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, antminer

I have an Antminer S9 where one of the chains is not hashing. In the logs I see the following:

```
get nonces on chain[7]
require nonce number:912
require validnonce number:57456
asic[00]=00 asic[01]=00 asic[02]=00 asic[03]=00 asic[04]=00 asic[05]=00 asic[06]=00 asic[07]=00 
asic[08]=00 asic[09]=00 asic[10]=00 asic[11]=00 asic[12]=00 asic[13]=00 asic[14]=00 asic[15]=00 
asic[16]=00 asic[17]=00 asic[18]=00 asic[19]=00 asic[20]=00 asic[21]=00 asic[22]=00 asic[23]=00 
asic[24]=00 asic[25]=00 asic[26]=00 asic[27]=00 asic[28]=00 asic[29]=00 asic[30]=00 asic[31]=00 
asic[32]=00 asic[33]=00 asic[34]=00 asic[35]=00 asic[36]=00 asic[37]=00 asic[38]=00 asic[39]=00 
asic[40]=00 asic[41]=00 asic[42]=00 asic[43]=00 asic[44]=00 asic[45]=00 asic[46]=00 asic[47]=00 
asic[48]=00 asic[49]=00 asic[50]=00 asic[51]=00 asic[52]=00 asic[53]=00 asic[54]=00 asic[55]=00 
asic[56]=00 asic[57]=00 asic[58]=00 asic[59]=00 asic[60]=00 asic[61]=00 asic[62]=00
```

followed by a whole stream of these (I don't think its necessary to paste all of them):

```
Below ASIC's core didn't receive all the nonce, they should receive 8 nonce each!

asic[00]=00
core[000]=0 core[001]=0 core[002]=0 core[003]=0 core[004]=0 core[005]=0 
core[006]=0 core[007]=0
```

Later in the logs, I see the following:

```
last_nonce_num:0
chain[5]: All chip cores are opened OK!
Test Patten on chain[5]: OK!
chain[6]: some chip cores are not opened FAILED!
Test Patten on chain[6]: FAILED!
chain[7]: some chip cores are not opened FAILED!
Test Patten on chain[7]: FAILED!
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is, and a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You yourself have stated that your boards are failing to hash.

It looks like some form of system test against the boards is failing.

I know I am being captain obvious here.
chain[6]: some chip cores are not opened **FAILED!**
**Test Patten** on chain[6]: **FAILED!**

Until you can find the point of failure with a volt meter, or replace the failing boards.

You can try tuning the voltage / frequency of the miner to see if this helps stabilize them.